# Argument type NSURL does not conform

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am working from an old tutorial swift2, Alamofire 3, but I am using swift 3, Alamofire 4.

I have changed most things successfully,  but I am running into a problem.
with this code area.

```
let url = NSURL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result
```

I am getting an error that says:

> Argument type NSURL does not conform to expected type
>   URLRequestConvertible.

it does give me the option of adding in as! URLRequestConvertible after the (url) but it crashes again after compile and when i press the button to get the info. it gives an error of:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSURL' (0x117e99338) to
>   'Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible' (0x1189ab120).

if I change NSURL to Url then it moves forward in the code but when it gets to the print statement it crashes and gives the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

here is that code below.

```
let url = URL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result



            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                if let weight = dict["weight"] as? String {
                    self._weight = weight
                }

                if let height = dict["height"] as? String {
                    self._height = height
                }

                if let baseAttack = dict["attack"] as? Int {
                    self._baseAttack = "\(baseAttack)"
                }



                if let defense = dict["defense"] as? Int {
                    self._defense = "\(defense)"
                }


                print(self._weight)
                print(self._height)
                print(self._baseAttack)
                print(self._defense)
```

I have tried to change all to Int but i get the same error.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me.

if it helps I put a break point in after print("Here") in the next code and it gives me the following error.

```
let url = URL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result

            print(result.value.debugDescription)
            print("Here")
```

error comes up:

> Optional({
>       "error_message" = "Sorry, this request could not be processed. Please try again later.";
>   })
>   Here

Thanks in advance,
Tony

Comment: The protocol name `URLRequestConvertible` implies you need an *(NS)URL**Request***.

Comment: Hi @vadian. when i change to NSURLRequest it asks me to change (string:  _pokemonUrl)!  to url: _pokemonUrl)! when i do it gives an error that cannot convert type string _pokemonUrl to argument type URL

Comment: Create an `(NS)URL` from the string and an `(NS)URLRequest` from the url. Please read the documentation of the requested classes or Quick Help by ⌥-clicking on the symbol or use code completion to get suggestions about the required types.

Comment: Sorry @vadian I'm fairly new to this, i looked at the quick helps but not sure how to read them. i am adding the code where it is created bellow. do i need to change it here.  `private var _pokemonUrl: String!
    var name: String {
        return _name

      _pokemonUrl = "\(URL_BASE)\(URL_POKEMON)\(self._pokedexId)/"
        
    }
    
    func downloadPokemonDetails(compleated: DownloadCompleate) {
    
        
        let url = NSURL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result`

Comment: Once again you have to create an URL `let url = URL(string: _pokemonUrl)!` and than a request `let request = URLRequest(url: url)` then call `Alamofire.request(request)....`

Comment: Thanks @vadian that works to getting the code to the next step.  `print(result.value.debugDescription)
            print("Here")` .   but i get the error Optional({
    "error_message" = "Sorry, this request could not be processed. Please try again later.";
})
Here which suggests that the data isn't being grabbed.

Answer (score 2):

You almost did it guys, just a cast to `URL` was missing.

```
let nsurl = NSURL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
let request = URLRequest(url: nsurl as URL)
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
   let result = response.result
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried folowing & it's helped

```
func downloadPokemonDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
        let url = URL(string: _pokemonUrl)!
        Alamofire.request(URLRequest(url: url)).responseJSON { response in
            if let result = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
                print(result.debugDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit?